# Unable to connect to unix:///var/run/docker.sock (Permission denied) from PHP code

Tags: php, api, sockets, unix, docker

I use Docker Windows Toolbox

I created the docker container with PHP-FPM:

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock php:7.0-fpm-alpine
```

If I use curl directly from container shell:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://containers/json
```

I got correct answer.

But if use PHP code:

```
$socket = stream_socket_client('unix:///var/run/docker.sock', $errno, $errstr);
if ($socket){
   $request = 'GET /version HTTP/1.1'."\r\n";
   $request.= 'Connection: Close'."\r\n\r\n";
   fwrite($socket,$request);
   $response = stream_get_contents($socket);
   fclose($socket);
   print_r($response);
}
else {
   print_r($errstr);
}
```

then I got the error below:

**Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to unix:///var/run/docker.sock (Permission denied)**

PHP works under www-data user. I tried to run PHP-FPM under root but got PHP-FPM error that I can't run php under root.

I tried to create "docker" user/group inside the container then ran PHP-FPM under "docker" user/group but it not helped.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could this could be a curl version issue. Support for unix socket in curl has been added relatively recently. Is the application code using the same curl as bash?

Comment: Mentioned PHP code doesn't use curl. I am unable to find approach using  PHP curl with socket.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `/var/run` has `r` and `x` privilege for all users and `docker.sock` and mode of `docker.sock` is `0777`

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to set 0777 permissions on the socket? Doesn't it mean that everybody can then use Docker on the machine without root permissions?

Answer (score 0):

change permission of docker.sock to 0755

`chmod 755 /var/run/docker.sock`

it's also work for all